# Render Error in my android emulator says "out of range"

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, android-emulator, jsx

When I run the app I'm working on through the Android emulator when I get to a certain screen I keep getting this error and can't find a solution to it. The error message is:

`scrollIndex out of range: requested index 5 is out of 0 to 20`

My issue is I'm not really familiar with that error message.
The code should be mapping out some dummy data and place that on the page.
I've tried to isolate the issue by commenting out pieces of code but that seems to not be making a difference.